# How to Group By using the distinct elements of an Array type column in Google BigQuery?

Tags: sql, group-by, google-bigquery, aggregation

I have two tables Table_1 and Table_2 in the database as below:

[image] [image]

The datatype of `Name` column is **STRING** and that of `Matches` column is **ARRAY<INT64>**. For each name, there can be one or more matches. For example, in `Table_1`, **N1** has matches **[1, 2]**. I want to combine both `Table_1` and `Table_2`, and generate a `Result` table like below:

[image]

In the Result table, the distinct match ID will come from the `Matches` column of both the tables and the `Names` column will show the names from both table related to the specific ID. For example, In `Table_1`, both `N1` and `N2` has a match with **1**. So, in the `Result` table, we will have a row for **1** with **N1, N2** as a comma separated in the `Names` column.

How can I achieve using Group BY and Aggregation in Google BigQuery?

Answer (score 1):

Consider below approach

```
select match, string_agg(name) names from (
  select name, match from table_1 t, t.matches match
  union all
  select name, match from table_2 t, t.matches match
)
group by match
```

if applied to sample data in your question - output is

[image]

Comment: have you tried?

Answer (score 0):

```
WITH Table_1 AS  
(
  SELECT 'N1' AS Name, [1,2] AS Matches UNION ALL
  SELECT 'N2' AS Name, [1,4] AS Matches UNION ALL
  SELECT 'N3' AS Name, [2,3] AS Matches
),
Table_2 AS  
(
  SELECT 'N2' AS Name, [10,11] AS Matches UNION ALL
  SELECT 'N4' AS Name, [12] AS Matches UNION ALL
  SELECT 'N5' AS Name, [10] AS Matches
)
SELECT
    Match,
    STRING_AGG(Name,', ' ORDER BY Name ASC) AS Names
FROM
    (
        SELECT
            Name,
            Match
        FROM 
            Table_1, 
            UNNEST(Table_1.Matches) AS Match
        UNION ALL
        SELECT
            Name,
            Match
        FROM 
            Table_2, 
            UNNEST(Table_2.Matches) AS Match
    )
GROUP BY
    Match
```

A slight addition to STRING_AGG to explicitly specify delimiter format as requested in the question.

[image: Query Output]